# Adobe Flex: How to Render/Remove Images Based on Database Result

Tags: image, apache-flex

In my database i'm storing a company's social media ID's. Obviously not all company's have all social media. In my database I have company ID's for: Facebook, Twitter, Youtube & Flickr.

All icons are listed in a  tag. I want to remove icons if the company does not have an ID for that social media. Currently if `twitterid == null` then the image will be set to `visible=false` but obviously there's a white space where the icon was supposed to go. I need to essentially move the next icon into that blank space. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaving out a lot of details and did not share your code, but I suspect that in addition to setting the visible property you also want to set the [includeInLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#includeInLayout) property.

Comment: @FinFlex It depends if you're using a container / layout inside the renderer that respects includeInLayout.  You will not be able to set includeInLayout on the top level component of the renderer.

Comment: Flextras, I'm not sure what I missed out. I haven't shown code because i've not actually done it yet, plus I have a lot of code that's not related to what i'm trying to achieve. So far I have a <s:HGroup> and inside there are 4 images. Also i've added the necessary code to access the user's social media page (click event) based on their ID, but you don't need to see that. I just don't know how to go about rendering only the icons for which the user has an ID.

Comment: @user1077544 I don't understand what you've tried; nor what hasn't worked; that is why you need to create a minimum viable sample demonstrating your problem and share your code.

Comment: That's because I don't quite know how to go about it in the first place. So far the images in my <s:HGroup> don't have x or y co-ordinates, so I tried setting one of them to visible = false to see if it would move the next icon into its slot and it didn't. I'll go away and try some things out now, including includeInLayout and see if I have any luck. If I don't i'll post in here again.

Comment: I think we're going in circles. Correct, an HGroup will ignore X and Y Values.  When you set visible to false, also set includeInLayout to false.  ( I already said that ) and the HGroup should not leave an open space for it.

Comment: Flextras, thankyou for the response. The includeInLayout does work. However my logic for deciding when an icon should appear does not. It seems that once an Icon has appeared, then I can't remove it. For example if I click on a business that has 0 social media then none, will show, then I click one with facebook, then the facebook image will show, but when I click another after this the facebook icon will always be there. I can't fit my code into this small box, so i've added it to Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/PbLd0YiK

Comment: Ok I've figured it out. There was nothing wrong with my logic, it was just that within the spark component I have the following code `includeInLayout="false"` whereas in my function it requires `includeInLayout=false` which is ridiculous. I don't know why it was different, or why I had no error in Flex for doing it with "". I've wasted about 2-3 hours there in testing to see if various parts work alone and trying different scenarios. Flextras your original suggestion was correct so I shall mark it so.

Comment: Without reviewing your code; I can't say why that oddity is happening.  I suppose it's possible that "false"--a string--is not the same as false--a reserved word.